# PCB ESD Ground Path analysis

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, ground-plane

[image]

[image]

We recently received this document from our battery pack supplier and it's intended to explain the ground path incase of ESD surge/spike.

I'm a beginner and I would appreciate it if someone on here can thoroughly explain how to read one of the ESD ground path analysis.

I'm interested on what to look for in ESD GND path, which components to observe, basically how to critic it and improve the design if need be.

Thanks as always

Comment: It's hard to see much of anything under the silkscreen. What are we looking at here? Is this a 2-layer board? Is there no contiguous ground plane in the design? What are the connectors, and to what do they connect?

Comment: this is a board for a battery pack,i'm assuming it's a 2 layer ,it's meant to show how ESD is dissipated away via the GND